# jQuery Select2 in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I don't know what's problem was

This is the return of select2:
[image: This is the return of select2]

and this is my code
HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <label class="form-label-bold">Jenis</label>
        <select class="select2 form-control" id="type" required>
            <option value="">Pilih</option>
            <option value="1">Head Office</option>
            <option value="2">Branch Office</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select2').select2({})
})
</script>
```

And this is cdn CSS:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your dropdown from screenshot. Please provide minimal example

Comment: that multiple select box sir

Comment: the original of select box should hidden and changes by select2 right? but on my case its not hide

Comment: i have tried it sir, but still the problems there

Comment: Create SO Snippet in your question, not just image

Comment: @holysix please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/Lk5orn3d/ it's work fine here

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyMgc.png, i guess you have other css files that mess around with the styling of select2

Comment: thanks everyone all of u made my day. i already solved this things. the problem because css collide each others. one more time, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give "multiple" in your select tag to get multiple selections.

```
<select class="select2 form-control" id="type" multiple required>
        <option value="">Pilih</option>
        <option value="1">Head Office</option>
        <option value="2">Branch Office</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need also to include the script tage for the select2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).